Static Resource in Head Markup of Experience Cloud Site not loading
I have the following script that I am trying to load in the Head Markup of an Experience Cloud site:
<script src= "https://static.soulmachines.com/widget-snippet-1.12.0.min.js" 
        data-sm-api-key="xxx"
        data-sm-position="bottomRight" 
        data-sm-greeting="Test" 
        data-sm-layout="fullFrame" 
        data-sm-profile-picture="https://siteURL/resource/1714710524000/staticresource?" >
</script>

The URL generated from the static resource is:
https://instanceURL/resource/1714710524000/staticresourcename?

When I use the same URL, it works in preview mode but doesn't work in authenticated user mode. If I replace the instance URL with the site URL, it doesn't load even in preview mode. The issue is that the data-sm-profile-picture loads in preview mode in Experience Cloud, but when I log in as an authenticated user, it doesn't load. I saw a similar post on the same topic, but it did not work for me. I appreciate your help.

Have you made sure the static resource is publicly visible?

@PhilW yes I did.

After much trial and error, I was able to resolve the issue by making the URL dynamic instead of static.
Instead of using a static URL like ../resource/1714710524000/staticresource, I made it dynamic by changing it to ../resource/{dynamic_value}/staticresource.
This allowed me to view the picture in the experience cloud site when I am authenticated.
I hope this solution helps others facing a similar issue!

This format is commonly used on Stack Exchange sites to share solutions and help others in the community.
